# Why chrome cannot translate a website?

Tags: google-chrome, language-translation

I am curious that why there are some websites that chrome can translate automatically to the chosen language while it cannot to others?

I have tried using several extensions but the website is not getting translated. Is there any possible explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a link to a particular case will help greatly but I can try to answer the general case. There are two main reasons:

1. Google does not know how to translate from a particular language
2. The webpage has confused the CLD.

The first is obvious so let me explain the second one. Chrome detects the webpage language using heuristics. They are in a package known as the compact language detector ([CLD](https://code.google.com/p/cld2/)). It is compact, which means it trades database size for accuracy; the non-compact, more accurate version being many times larger.

So assuming that the page in question is in a popular language, there must be something in the sequence of text characters that is confusing the CLD which either does not know what language the page is using *or* it thinks is using a language that Google does not know how to translate.

Comment: I was trying to set up a multi-lingual website, and I figured out that I had to add the link to [link]( https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) and use the js snippet

Comment: Chrome without any extension can translate many sites that have not been added via the translate manager link you mention. This is just built-in the browser.

Comment: You have "<html class="no-js" lang="en">". You are telling Chrome the page is in English.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation